# Preflight failing while adding Authorization header - React + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to communicate with the nodejs server , "Preflight" getting failed while adding Authorization header , with out header i am able to connect with server. Screen shot for request header from browser development tool is added below

## CORS added to the server.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
```

## React JS - Axios Code

```
let params = {
      "userId": userName,
      "password": password,
      "random": event.target.name,
      "grant_type": "password"
    };
    var config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic YXBwbGljYXRpb246c2VjcmV0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }


[Axios.post('/oauth/token', params, config).then((response) => {

      if (response.status === 200) {
        if (response.data.querySuccess) {
          console.log(response);
    }
    ).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert.error('Oops some error occured please check the data you have submitted');
    });
  }][1]
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to answer this with the information provided. Can you show us the order in which the middleware you have shared is declared with respect to the POST and OPTIONS route handlers? (ie, I believe this may be being caused as you do not have an OPTIONS request handler OR the middleware is not being applied before the OPTIONS request is triggered)

Comment: refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: Middle ware is added after the CORS definitions
Usage of middleware 
=====================
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", clientURL);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  next();
});
app.use('/bcl/vtng',votingRouter);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723370/react-connecting-to-node-cors-preflight-failure

Comment: @Golwin i have verified the answer and added the cors library and used but now body parameters are not detecting , it refers missing parameters

Comment: @ChiragRavindra and Golwin
Thanks for your valuable comments - issue was related with CORS only , i am able to resolve it